# Swift func to provide current CLLocation (with closures NOT delegates)

Tags: swift, core-location

I would like to create an Swift func like that:

```
static func queryLocation(desiredAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy, completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocation, Error>)->())
```

This func would be as simple as it can get. As caller, you don't need to hold on to your location manager and you don't need to implement any delegate methods. Just ask for the location and implement the completion handler.

(original source code removed and added as answer, because it actually worked - I just had issues calling it properly)

Comment: Is there someone who holds a strong reference to `OneTimeLocation`? If not, then the instance will deallocate, and this could be the reason why the delegate is not called.

Comment: @Cristik: yes, the static var "instances" is supposed to do only that.

Comment: Just tried your code on a simulator, got the expected behaviour: the delegates were called, the completion was executed.

Comment: (?)  I only see the authorization alert, then I answer that with "yes, once" and after that, no more delegates are being called. It should at least call didChangeAuthorization after a clean install.

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the console? Myself often forget to add the appropriate Info.plist keys

Comment: no warnings, the alert is properly initialized with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. @Christik: thanks for your test, I will do more debugging.

Comment: @Christik: I'm sorry for the hassle. Seems like the caller was doing a DispatchGroup.wait(), but that doesn't go along with CLLocation authorization requests very well. I feel like I should answer my own question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone. There was a problem with the calling method. The OneTimeLocation class is actually working as expected. (also available as Swift Package: https://github.com/hoereth/CoreLocationUtils/blob/main/Sources/CoreLocationUtils/OneTimeLocation.swift)

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

public class OneTimeLocation : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    public enum LocationError : Error {
        case denied
        case restricted
        case timeout
        case unknown
    }
    
    let manager: CLLocationManager
    let completion: (Result<CLLocation, Error>)->()
    let timeout: TimeInterval

    fileprivate static let instancesQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "OneTimeLocation.instances")
    fileprivate static var instances = Set<OneTimeLocation>()
    
    /// Will either find you the current location or produce an error.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - desiredAccuracy: see CLLocationManager.desiredAccuracy
    ///   - timeout: Applies to actual finding a location. Dialogs are presented without timeout.
    public static func queryLocation(desiredAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy, timeout: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocation, Error>)->()) {
        let oneTimeLocation = OneTimeLocation(desiredAccuracy: desiredAccuracy, completion: completion, timeout: timeout)
        oneTimeLocation.manager.delegate = oneTimeLocation
        
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            instancesQueue.sync {
                _ = instances.insert(oneTimeLocation)
                oneTimeLocation.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeout) {
                    oneTimeLocation.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                    completion(Result.failure(LocationError.timeout))
                    oneTimeLocation.removeInstance()
                }
            }
        case .notDetermined:
            instancesQueue.sync {
                _ = instances.insert(oneTimeLocation)
                oneTimeLocation.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        case .denied:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.denied))
        case .restricted:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.restricted))
        @unknown default:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.unknown))
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate init(desiredAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy, completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocation, Error>)->(), timeout: TimeInterval) {
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.desiredAccuracy = desiredAccuracy
        self.completion = completion
        self.timeout = timeout
    }
    
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if (locations.count > 0) {
            self.completion(Result.success(locations[0]))
        } else {
            self.completion(Result.failure(LocationError.unknown))
        }
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.removeInstance()
    }
    
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.completion(Result.failure(error))
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.removeInstance()
    }
    
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeout) {
                self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.completion(Result.failure(LocationError.timeout))
                self.removeInstance()
            }
        case .notDetermined:
            break;
        case .denied:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.denied))
            self.removeInstance()
        case .restricted:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.restricted))
            self.removeInstance()
        @unknown default:
            completion(Result.failure(LocationError.unknown))
            self.removeInstance()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func removeInstance() {
        Self.instancesQueue.sync {
            _ = OneTimeLocation.instances.remove(self)
        }
    }
}
```